# Error while loading web map components using react-native-maps and Expo

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

I'm trying to run react-native-maps on web using Expo and react-native.
while loading the web page I'm facing a couple of console errors altogether when all of them referring issues with loading and exporting components at the library.

The errors:

> export 'Animated' was not found in './lib/components/MapView'

> export 'MAP_TYPES' was not found in './lib/components/MapView'

> export 'ProviderPropType' was not found in './lib/components/MapView'

> export 'requireNativeComponent' was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'

All the errors refring to the specific lines in the library where it's fails.

It seems that its unable to import and re-export Animated, MAP_TYPES, ProviderPropType components and can't find 'requireNativeComponent'

Has anybody faced that issue? any solution?

Expo ver. : 45.0.0
react-native-maps ver. : 0.17.7